# Cannot find name 'FB' [ts]

Tags: facebook-graph-api, react-tsx

I am trying to initialize JavaScript SDK to use Facebook Graph API eventually. But it keep saying that `Cannot find name FB`, not sure why. Here is what I did,

```
componentDidMount() {
    (window as any).fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({ // this FB errors out
            appId            : "my-app-id",
            autoLogAppEvents : true,
            xfbml            : true,
            version          : "v2.11"
        });
    };

    (function(d: any, s: any, id: any) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return; }
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, "script", "facebook-jssdk"));
}
```

P.S. I am using `TSLint`, that is why I have all those `typedef any`

Comment: have you tried with "window.fbAsyncInit" instead, and without those weird TSLint additions in general? where does it say that it cannot find FB? somewhere else, or right at FB.init?

Comment: right at `FB.init`. No, I haven't tried without `TSLint`, because its pretty much useless to me if it doesn't work with `TSLint`.

Comment: do you have a test link for us? with the information at hand, we can only say that the js sdk is not getting loaded. which is exactly what the error message says.

Comment: `FB` is a global `window` object (`window.FB`) provided when https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js is loaded. For tslint to know where this global FB namespace comes from you need to declare it in your respective lint rc or define an interface for it.

Answer (score 12):

Install https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/facebook-js-sdk and add `facebook-js-sdk` to `types` in your `tsconfig.ts` or `tsconfig.app.json` if you have nested applications when using Angular CLI.

Example `tsconfig.app.json`:

```
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../../out-tsc/app",
    "types": [
      "node",
      "gapi", // google
      "gapi.auth2", // google
      "facebook-js-sdk" // facebook
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```